# Using jest's test.each vs. looping with forEach

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Is there a reason I would prefer one method over the other? Here are some examples:

```
describe('some tests', () => {
  [1, 2, 3].forEach(num => {
    test(`${num}: test`, () => {
      doSomeTestStuff(num)
    }) 
  })

  // vs.

  test.each([1, 2, 3])('%s: test', (num) => {
    doSomeTestStuff(num)
  })
})
```

It seems kind of difficult to read the `test.each` syntax, especially when you can just do native javascript iteration to achieve what seems to be the same effect. Teardown/setup still happens the same way (from what I can tell).

Answer (score 6):

I would prefer the vanilla JS `forEach` version, because it's just JavaScript. This means:

- You don't need to be familiar with Jest specifically, you don't need to go looking in the docs for what exactly `test.each` does. The `` test.each`table` `` form particularly can behave in a way that's surprising, see e.g. [Jest test.each with literal table: "Not enough arguments supplied for given headings"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70804721/3001761).
- Equally it's portable between test frameworks, you can use the same approach in Mocha, Tap, etc.
- You get proper IDE support - you need to wait for runtime to find out whether `'.add($a, $b)'` actually matches the properties in the objects, whereas `` `.add(${a}, ${b})` `` can be checked and autocompleted statically (and manipulated however you like, as you can interpolate arbitrary expressions).

---

It's not true that there's any difference in the way the tests are executed or reported. The `forEach` loop runs at test *discovery* time, and all three tests are registered. Then they're all run, separately, at *execution* time. You'd only see problems with failures impacting other cases if you moved the loop *inside* a single test case, e.g.:

```
describe('some bad tests', () => {
  // this an example of how not to do it
  test('num tests', () => {
    [1, 2, 3].forEach(num => {
      doSomeTestStuff(num)
    }) 
  })
})
```

---

One other thing to note with the vanilla `forEach` approach is that it is common, as you've shown, to inline the arrays of test cases. If you're relying on [ASI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#automatic_semicolon_insertion), as your examples suggest you are, this sometimes means you need to *prefix* the array with `;`:

```
describe('some tests', () => {
  [1, 2, 3].forEach(num => {
    test(`${num}: test`, () => {
      doSomeTestStuff(num)
    }) 
  })

  ;[4, 5, 6].forEach(num => {
    test(`${num}: test`, () => {
      doSomeTestStuff(num)
    }) 
  })
})
```

Without this, you'd get `TypeError: Cannot read property '6' of undefined`.

This is maybe a vote in Jest's favour, but if you're not going to use semicolons you *do* need to know when they will and won't get inserted - I'd argue it's a vote in *semicolons'* favour.

Answer (score 2):

Great question!

On the surface it would seem like the two are basically equivalent, but there are a few reasons why you may want to use `.each` instead.

- If an expectation in a `forEach` fails, it'll fail immediately and stop execution. This leaves you in the dark on whether the other tests in the `forEach` passed or failed. With `.each` it is basically writing a separate and distinct test for each item in your array.
- If an expectation in a `forEach` fails, it's not always obvious which item in the array caused the failure. In a `.each` you automatically get context from the unique test name.
- With `.each` you can use [tagged template literals](https://github.com/mattphillips/jest-each#tagged-template-literal-of-rows) to handle multiple parameters easily, and as parameters grow the `.each` can be very expressive and much more readable than an array with arbitrary values.
- Since, as I said before, `.each` creates a separate test for each item, the final report will make it seem like you wrote more tests than you actually have. Just a small thing that brings satisfaction when you look at the final output.

Comment: "If an expectation in a forEach fails, it'll fail immediately and stop execution."
That doesn't seem to be the case.
https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-playground-forked-0v47q?file=/src/sum.test.js

You may configure Jest to bail after x number of tests failed, but that's not the default behavior. The default behavior is described here:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#bail-number--boolean

Comment: Sorry for the poor wording. I don't mean that the whole test file will stop execution, just that one test case so it won't complete the `forEach` loop. It will still continue onto the next test case. Hopefully that clears up the confusion!

Comment: I'm just wondering, why I see 1 test passed and 1 test failed in the codesandbox, both within the same forEach loop, when that's the case.

Comment: The first and fourth bullets in this answer are inaccurate. The `forEach` completes, registering all three tests, _then_ they're executed. They're separate tests that will be executed and reported separately. A failure would only stop the rest of the cases if the loop was _inside_ the test case. For the second note the OP is setting unique names in the `forEach` too.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It seems like the second bullet isn't accurate either as OP's code also changes the test name as well.

I am really curious what (if anything) `each` is doing that a `forEach` is not - the source code for it is much longer than a few lines!

Comment: BTW @ScottHampton has done a great job explaining why .each is superior to a loop *inside* the test.  It just doesn't address the two code snippets that OP posted.

Answer (score 0):

One advantage of `test.each` can be better tool support. I just noticed this with the VS Code plugin *orta.vscode-jest*.