# Jest's `it.each` causes a 'Expected done to be called once, but it was called multiple times' error when used with 'getByTestId'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, jest-dom

I have a component with some parts that are conditionally rendered based on some config on the `window` object. This all works, I can confirm this manually.

I have this sort of test setup, but I have simplified it somewhat:

```js
it('renders both by default', () => { // PASS
  const Comp = getComponent();
  render(<Comp />);
  expect(screen.getByTestId('one')).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(screen.getByTestId('two')).toBeInTheDocument();
})
it.each([
  { testId: 'one', otherTestId: 'two'},
  { testId: 'two', otherTestId: 'one' },
])('renders $testId, not $otherTestId', (testId, otherTestId) => { // FAIL
  delete window.config[otherTestId]; // this works
  const Comp = getComponent();
  render(<Comp />);
  expect(screen.getByTestId(testId)).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(screen.getByTestId(otherTestId)).not.toBeInTheDocument();
})
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Expected done to be called once, but it was called multiples times. Reason 'two'.
```

Which is not something I've ever seen before. None of my tests that are running here are async. The component isn't async. I'm not using done anywhere near this.

What's happening?

Comment: i maybe wrong here, but I feel changing the arrow function to  `({ testId, otherTestId }) => ` would fix the issue

Comment: @boop_the_snoot that gives me a different error but *making* this async, destructuring them and calling `done` does  almost work. The different error is probably due to something else I'm doing wrong

Comment: @boop_the_snoot I fixed my other issue and that does work! It's very odd I got that error but I can see why it happened!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You need to destructure your test variables

Jest is expecting `testId` to be an object containing all your test variables, and  `otherTestId` to be the function `done`.

I'm not sure why it thinks it's called multiple times, but making the first argument:

```
{ testId, otherTestId }
```

Works around this, and matches the documentation correctly.

---

Alternatively, follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72117404/3001761) for replacing jest's for loop with the native one, which is a better approach in many ways.