# Test case for each scenario for if-else condition

Tags: angular, jestjs

```
rateTermCalc() {
    if (this.termYearsDiff(this.remainingDays, 1, 182)) {
      this.termText = '6 months';
    } else if (this.termYearsDiff(this.remainingDays, 183, 365)) {
      this.termText = '1 year';
    } else if (this.termYearsDiff(this.remainingDays, 366, 730)) {
      this.termText = '2 years';
    } else if (this.termYearsDiff(this.remainingDays, 731, 1095)) {
      this.termText = '3 years';
    } else if (this.termYearsDiff(this.remainingDays, 1096, 1460)) {
      this.termText = '4 years';
    } else if (this.termYearsDiff(this.remainingDays, 1461, 1825)) {
      this.termText = '5 years';
    } else if (this.termYearsDiff(this.remainingDays, 1826, 2555)) {
      this.termText = '7 years';
    } else 
    this.termText = '10 years';
  }

  termYearsDiff(x: number, min: number, max: number): boolean {
    return x >= min && x <= max;
  }
```

I am trying to write Jest unit test case in Angular for above function. How to write using `it.each`?

Comment: Did you _try_ using `it.each` (note https://stackoverflow.com/q/57171579/3001761)? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this:

```js
describe('rateTermCalc', () => {
  let component: YourComponentClass; // replace with the actual name of your class

  beforeEach(() => {
    component = new YourComponentClass();
    // If you can spy on termYearsDiff, do so here. Otherwise, you might need to refactor your code.
    jest.spyOn(component, 'termYearsDiff').mockImplementation((x, min, max) => x >= min && x <= max);
  });

  it.each([
    [181, '6 months'],
    [183, '1 year'],
    [365, '1 year'],
    [366, '2 years'],
    [730, '2 years'],
    [731, '3 years'],
    [1095, '3 years'],
    [1096, '4 years'],
    [1460, '4 years'],
    [1461, '5 years'],
    [1825, '5 years'],
    [1826, '7 years'],
    [2555, '7 years'],
    [2556, '10 years'],
  ])('should set termText correctly for remainingDays %i', (remainingDays, expectedTermText) => {
    component.remainingDays = remainingDays;
    component.rateTermCalc();
    expect(component.termText).toBe(expectedTermText);
  });
});
```

Breakdown of what I did:

Step 1. **Mock the `termYearsDiff` function**: Since `termYearsDiff` is a method of the same class, I don't think you can easily spy on it (could be wrong on this..my angular spy knowledge is rusty at best), but let's assume you can. If not, you might need to refactor your code to make it something a bit more testable.

Step 2. **Set up the test table**: For `it.each`, you'll set up a table where each row represents a test case. Each row will contain:

- The value of `this.remainingDays`.
- The expected value of `this.termText`.

Step 3. **Write the test**: For each test case, you'll set the value of `this.remainingDays`, call `rateTermCalc`, and then check if `this.termText` matches the expected value.

***NOTE:*** I did this primarily pseudocode with what you provided...didn't run this locally or in an editor since it would just error on my without your full `termYearDiff` code, I couldn't fully gleam the `termYearDiff` algo, but have general idea of what its doing,  and i was too lazy to write my scaffolding code for this...but if you provide more detail we could get a working example going.

Comment: Why replace the real implementation with a test double that does _the same thing_?!