# How to use `it.each`/ `describe.each` in Node.js native test runner?

Tags: node.js, node-test-runner

How can I use `it.each`/`describe.each`, like in Jest or Vitest, for the native Node.js test runner?

Comment: Don't bother, just write a loop - that's portable to any runner/framework: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72117404/3001761

Comment: bad IDE support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until and unless [`nodejs/node#47902`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/47902) is resolved:

1. install `jest-each` (`npm install --save-dev jest-each`)
2. create `add-each-support.js` file with the code below

   ```js
   const {default: each} = require('jest-each');
   const { it, test, describe } = require('node:test');

   const eachWithNode = each.withGlobal({
       describe,
       it,
       test
   })

   // This is needed for the jest-each to work
   it.concurrent = test.concurrent = () => {
       throw new Error('concurrent is not supported, added just to allow it.each and describe.each');
   };

   describe.each = function (...args) {
       return eachWithNode(...args).describe;
   };
   it.each = (...args) => {
       return eachWithNode(...args).it;
   };

   test.each = (...args) => {
       return eachWithNode(...args).test;
   };
   ```
3. when running tests, require this file:

   ```bash
   node --require ./add-each-support.js <rest-of-your-test-command>
   ```