# How to use dynamic substitution for Jest functions?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a series of test cases like this:

```
  it('should render button disabled', async () => {
    render(...);

    const button = screen.getByRole("button");
    expect(button ).toBeDisabled();
  });
```

for some cases, it will be button disabled. I am trying to use `it.each()` to test instead of writing individual cases.

For such situation, the test will be `toBeEnabled()` and `toBeDisabled()`. In other cases, it would involve more function. Is it possible to use variables for these Jest functions?

Comment: It's just JavaScript, `expect(value)[method]()` would work. But I'd be more inclined to split those into two parameterised cases. Also FYI it's often easier to use regular JS than Jest's "each": https://stackoverflow.com/a/72117404/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes. Agree that should be 2 cases.  But I found a way around it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that I can check the enable/disable by testing the property.

```
  it('should render button disabled', async () => {
    render(...);

    const button = screen.getByRole("button");
    expect(button ).toHaveProperty('disabled', <variable>);
  });
```

Comment: This might work in your specific case, but note the [`toBe{Disabled,Enabled}` matcher](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/blob/main/src/to-be-disabled.js) is a **lot** more complex than just _"does the element have the disabled property?"_

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, I fully agree.  In different situations, I'll probably need to use other ways to handle this depending on the situation.